# actionscript error: Call to a possibly undefined method

Tags: flash, class, actionscript

those files are in the same folder:

my .as file
 package {public function YAAY():int{return(3);};  }

my main .fla
 trace(YAAY());

but the compiler says
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method YAAY.

I think I made an obvious mistake, but I can't figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to correctly define your class inside the .as file. It should look like:

```
package {
    public class YAAYClass {
        public static function YAAY():int {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Have it called this way:

```
trace(YAAYClass.YAAY());
```

Comment: nah, Now it said
1120: Access of undefined property YAAYClass.
I think the .fla not even see the .as file.

Comment: The .as file should be named "YAAYClass" in order to work properly.

Comment: yeah true. but creating a class was unnecessary. it could be played with a single function in a package.

Answer (score 0):

1: I should have named my .as file "YAAY.as" because this is the externally visible function in the file.
2: I should have type in my main .fla file that "import YAAY"
thats it, problem solved, no classes needed